# Curl command and slim php

Tags: php, post, curl, command-line, slim

I want to post data and headers from curl in the command line and through php curl. I am using this in the commandline:

```
curl -X POST -H "API_KEY:1234" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
--data "url=http://example.com/storage/testing.pdf" http://fake.com/index.php/tp
```

**The output I get:** 1234

and in PHP:

```
<?php



$header = array();
$header[] = 'API_KEY:1234';

$postdata =  array('url' => "http://example.com/storage/testing.pdf");
            $ch = curl_init("localhost/fake.com/index.php/tp");

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
            $result = curl_exec($ch); 


            curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

**The output I get:** 1234http://example.com/storage/testing.pdf

I use the following in SLIM php framework:

```
$app->map('/tp', function() use ($app) {

 $postvar = $app->request->post('url');

      $headers = $app->request->headers;

        $apikey = $app->request->headers->get('API_KEY');

        echo $apikey;
        echo $postvar;


})->via('POST');
```

I do not why posting from the command line does not give me the post variables in SLIM. Please help.

Comment: Try removing  -H "Content-Type: application/json" since you are actually posting application/x-www-form-urlencoded data.

Comment: Actually, he is posting `multipart/form-data` data. Curl set's the `Content-Type` to this, when the `value` for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is an array.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: PHP version yes. I suggested removing the -H switch from commandline version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that the request needed an SSL certificate.
I solved it by adding this line to the cURL parameters.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```